# android sdk manager and avd manager icons are not showing in my eclipse

Tags: android

[image]

trying to reinstall the ADT plug in but Android SDK and AVD manager not showing.

Comment: What steps did you take to reinstall the plugin? You should double-check that it has actually installed.

Comment: http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/11/01/install-android-development-environment-on-windows-7/

Comment: When you create a new project, are the Android options available? If not, then the plugin probably has not been installed correctly. Try repeating the steps from the link you gave starting at "Install the Android plugin for Eclipse and point to the Android SDK".

Comment: for pointing to android sdk ,i already setup my avd previously.

Comment: So are you reinstalling or trying to fix a previous install?

Comment: fixing previous one..

Comment: uninstalled adt and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in JavaEE perspective ,changed it to Java perspective . now AVD manager and SDK manager is showing.

Answer (score 16):

On Eclipse:
Navigate with menus-

1. Window
2. Customize perspective
3. Command group availability tab
4. On the check box, android SDK and AVD manager check it
5. Click ok

Answer (score 0):

Click on the BIG blue button

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Do not setup the Android development environment from Eclipse itself. It is cumbersome. Download an eclipse version, which Google had already done all the proper configuration for you.